# Java - Why is my static variable being set to null?

Tags: java, javafx, static, java-8, javafx-8

EDIT 1: I think I may have figured it out.

Here is my initialize() method

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter());
    groupList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(obs -> {
        Group.setSelectedGroup(groupList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        handleGroupSelected();
    });
```

I think that when I reload the groupList ListView this selectedItemProperty listener is being called and setting it to null.

I have fixed this by adding an if condition inside the listener:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter());
    groupList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(obs -> {
        if(groupList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
            Group.setSelectedGroup(groupList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            handleGroupSelected();
        }
    });
```

---

For some reason my static 'selectedGroup' variable is being set to null and I cannot figure out why.

I have carried out the following troubleshooting.

I have a method called 'refresh()' which calls a method called 'createGroupFilter()'. I have included the following System.out.println statements in order to see when the variable is getting nulled.

```
private void refresh() {
    System.out.println("before groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter()); "  + Group.getSelectedGroup()); //TROUBLESHOOTING
    groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter());
    System.out.println("after groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter()); "  + Group.getSelectedGroup()); //TROUBLESHOOTING
    if(Group.getSelectedGroup() != null) {
        groupList.getSelectionModel().select(Group.getSelectedGroup());
        int n = groupList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        groupList.getFocusModel().focus(n);
        groupList.scrollTo(n);
        userList.setItems(createUserFilter());
        if(User.getSelectedUser() != null) {
            userList.getSelectionModel().select(User.getSelectedUser());
        }
    }
}

private FilteredList<Group> createGroupFilter() {
    System.out.println("start createGroupFilter(); " + Group.getSelectedGroup()); //TROUBLESHOOTING
    groups = MainScreenModel.getGroups();
    FilteredList<Group> filteredGroups = new FilteredList<Group>(groups, s -> true);
    groupSearchTxt.textProperty().addListener(obs -> {
        String filter = groupSearchTxt.getText().toLowerCase();
        if(filter == null || filter.trim().length() == 0) {
            filteredGroups.setPredicate(s -> true);
        } else {
            filteredGroups.setPredicate(s -> s.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filter));
        }
    });
    System.out.println("end createGroupFilter(); " + Group.getSelectedGroup()); //TROUBLESHOOTING
    return filteredGroups;
}
```

This provides the following output:

```
before groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter()); Group 1
start createGroupFilter(); Group 1
end createGroupFilter(); Group 1
after groupList.setItems(createGroupFilter()); null
```

**So it appears to me that the groupList.setItems()... is what is causing the issue.**

For reference, here is the MainScreenModel.getGroups() method:

```
public static ObservableList<Group> getGroups() {
    ObservableList<Group> groups = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = DatabaseConnection.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY group_name ASC");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String gn = rs.getString("GROUP_NAME");
            String desc = rs.getString("DESCRIPTION");
            groups.add(new Group(gn, desc));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return groups;
}
```

And also my Group class:

```
public class Group {

    private static Group selectedGroup;

    private final StringProperty groupName   = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Group(String hn, String desc) {
        setGroupName(hn);
        setDescription(desc);
    }

    public StringProperty hostNameProperty() {
        return this.groupName;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return this.groupName.get();
    }

    public void setGroupName(String hn) {
        this.groupName.set(hn);
    }

    public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description.get();
    }

    public void setDescription(String desc) {
        this.description.set(desc);
    }

    public static Group getSelectedGroup() {
        return selectedGroup;
    }

    public static void setSelectedGroup(Group group) {
        selectedGroup = group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.groupName.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the setSelectedGroup() method ever set it to null?

Comment: I can't see any place where you set it, or am I missing something?

Comment: I was about say the same, where are you filling `static Group selectedGroup;`

Comment: I don't see the declaration for **groupList**. What type is it? If it's custom can we get the source for setItems()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot see anywhere that you call `setSelectedGroup` in your code.  Since `selectedGroup` is default initialized to `null`, it is going to remain `null` if you don't call `setSelectedGroup`.

On the other hand, if (as it appears) `selectedGroup` is non-null at certain points, then some code *that you haven't shown us<sup>1</sup>* must be calling the method.  A Java variable won't change its value spontaneously.

So ....

---

> Why is my static variable being set to null?

Something must be calling `setSelectedGroup` somewhere with a `null` parameter.

> So it appears to me that the groupList.setItems()... is what is causing the issue.

That is plausible.  It is also possible that something else is causing it; e.g. another thread.

---

<sup>1 - That was the problem.</sup>